# How does SQL server insert data parallely between applications?

Tags: sql-server

I have two applications.
One inserts data into database continuously like it is having an infinity loop.

When the second application inserts data to same database and table what will happen.

If it waits till the other application to complete inserting which will handle this?

Or it will say it is busy?

Or code throws an exception?

Comment: This depends on several things like do you have transaction and what is your isolation level, what is your clustered index and what kind of data are you inserting. The inserts block only minimal part of the table and if the second insert isn't inserting to the same part, it will be done at the same time.

Comment: Not to mention you tagged three different DBMS. The answer will not be the same for all of them.

Comment: Oh yes, didn't even look at if there's more than SQL Server, so just disregard my comment if you're working with something else -- and tag the correct one only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL servers have something called a connection pool which means that more than once connection to the database can be made at any particular time, and that's where the easy bit ends.

If you were to for example connect to the database on two applications at the same time and insert data in to different tables from each application then the two could happily happen at the same time without issue.

If however those applications wanted to do something like edit the same row then there's an issue with "locking" ...

Essentially any operation on a SQL database requires "acquiring a lock" on a "set" or "row" or "cell" depending on the configuration of the server its hard to say what might happen in your case.

So the simple answer is:
Yes, SQL can make stuff happen (like inserts) at the same time but with some clauses.

And long answer ...
requires in depth knowledge of locking and your database and server configuration.

Comment: But here the 1st application inserting continously. Will the second application inserts queued or insert by time the query came.

Comment: that also depends on things like transactions ... each statement is executed as a transaction that gets put in the "transaction log" but if you wrap statements in a transaction they all get committed at once or not at all. so the second app may have to wait to get a lock on the table.